# Using excel vba, is there an easy way to say "if any of the functions or child subs was exited, then exit the macro"?

Tags: excel, vba

My (main) sub called several functions and child subs. If there is "exit function" or "exit sub" line in those functions and child subs, and when it was executed, is there an easy way to exit my main sub right after? I thought about using a number as a flag but I have many functions. Is there an easier way of doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first idea is also to use a flag or a global variable and right now I do not see any easier way to do it.

So I think you need to do sth similar to this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
Dim exitMain As Boolean: exitMain = False

    Call A(12, exitMain)
    If exitMain Then
        MsgBox "Exit because of A"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call B(3, exitMain)
    If exitMain Then
        MsgBox "Exit because of B"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Reached end of main"

End Sub

Sub A(val1 As Long, cancel As Boolean)

    If val1 = 2 Then
        cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Reached end of A"

End Sub

Sub B(val1 As Long, cancel As Boolean)

    If val1 = 3 Then
        cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Reached end of B"

End Sub
```